# Expectations, Logarithm, and Exponents

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, expected-value

Is it true that:
$$E_t\bigg[\dfrac{exp(f(x))}{E_t\big[exp(f(x))\big]} log(E_t(exp(f(x))))\bigg] = log(E_t(exp(f(x)))),$$
where $E_t$ is the expectation given information in $t$?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, use linearity of expectations.

Comment: Cool cool, thanks!